# What distribution model should be used to model customer arrival times?

Tags: probability, queueing-theory

I have this multiple choice problem that is testing my understanding of distribution models. I cannot come up with the correct one to solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> Your website provides valuable information to the public. Due to your
>   encryption protocols, service  requirements and speed, and frequency
>   of internet traffic, you must design your server such that it  can
>   handle an average of 2 fee-paying connections at any given time. The
>   design and systems needed  to achieve the average of 2 (as well as
>   satisfy your budget constraints) will permit only a maximum of  4
>   fee-paying connections at any given time. Thus, when there are 4
>   fee-paying connections, the  system blocks others from signing on.
>   What percentage of time will the system block customers  from signing
>   on?

```
a. 6.25% 
b. 27% 
c. 9% 
d. 4.5% 
e. cannot be determined with the material we covered in class this semester 
f. 22.5% 
g. 18% 
h. 13.5% 
i. 2.5%
```

The right answer is "c", 9%. I have no idea how to arrive at this answer.

Comment: Since it is not practical to reproduce the material that answer e refers to, I am just going to say that you need *a lot* more hypotheses to arrive at answer c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a M/M/c/c, in equilibrium!, the expected value of customers in the queue is given by: $$\mathbb{E}[n]=\rho (1-P_c),$$
where $\rho$ is the service rate and $P_c$ is the probability of full system ($n=c$) - blocking! From literature, we know $$P_n = \frac{\rho^n}{n!} \left[ \sum_{i=0}^{c} \frac{\rho^n}{n!} \right]^{-1}.$$

So, numerically evaluating them, the only solution $(\rho,P_4) \in \mathbb{R}_{+} \times (0,1)$ is
$$(\rho,P_4) = (2.289428485,\, 0.12641953).$$

Which is none of the available answers.

Probably your teacher was expecting and "e", and never had put the time check it. =P

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I very much appreciate the mathematical explanation and help that you have provided. Unfortunately, as the case with college education, the correct answer is whatever the professor says it is.

After doing some more digging, I managed to figure arrive at the answer in a somewhat weird way. Please tell me if the following analysis is correct. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Identify the maximum of 4 concurrent connections as the 95 % service level on the normal distribution due to the central limit theorem. 
2. The mean of the normal distribution is 1 x n. 
3. The Z-Score associated with the 95 % service level is 1.645.
4. The standard distribution of this normal distribution is 1 x SQRT(n). 
5. -1.65 = (4-1xn)/(1xSQRT(n)) solve for n. n = 8.91 or approximately 9 % 
Does that make any sense?

Comment: Dear @RayLi. I could not really follow what you said. Can you write it using Mathjax?

Comment: Also, my answer is from what I've gotten from the problem, but might be wrong because the text was a little bit confusing.

Comment: and I have to say I don't think your solution is proper. Can you tell me later how your grader solved it?

Comment: Dear @RayLi, was it right after all?

Comment: Don't worry! I haven't forgot this problem. I plan on finding out the answer by asking my instructor. Will report back when I have the answer!